# Android multi language support without localization

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm working on a android project.

I want to provide multiple language support for the applciation. 
I researched about it but I found almost everything with localization.

Is there any way to do this without using localization?

My preference is using language support for localization or supported versions.

I mean user can switch the languages in application.

Can I do this with multiple value files?

Comment: have you got solved his problem ..??

Comment: user999822 do u got solve or not for your question if you got post here your trick or code

Answer (score 4):

Use this to change the language by code--

```
 Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
 Locale.setDefault(locale);
 Configuration config = new Configuration();
 config.locale = locale;
 context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Write the countrycode of language in place of "en_US" whatever language you want...like for japanese--"ja_JP" For Arabic--"ar" or check this link for code of country--

http://code.google.com/apis/igoogle/docs/i18n.html

And make a folder in  **res/values-ja**  for japanese or  **res/values-ar**  for arabic..

And make  **string.xml** file And put the languages whatever you want on your layout..
It will fetch the default language from values folder otherwise you want it manually then it will fetch from your external folder values-ar etc. like...

Its example of res/values-ar for arabic--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <resources>
     <string name="spinner_label">تصفية حسب</string>
     <string name="app_name">2011 فرق</string> 
     <string name="search">بحث :</string>
  </resource>
```

Hope It will help you..

Comment: is it supported for SDK version 7 ?

Comment: it depends on the languages..like japanese language will support from 1.5 version..and most of the languagues supports from 2.3.3 version..

Comment: i am testing this on 2.3.3 and emulator both of them have en-us language working language are not change while i have change or use for japanes Locale locale = new Locale("ja "); where i am wrong ??

Comment: @Hulk i follow your way but did not get where i am wrong i am trying to do it in language English -us "en-us" japanes "ja" Hindi "hi" and same as string i have put in res/values/string.xml

Comment: @amitsharma: Use "ja_JP" for japanese as argument

Comment: If you are changing the language while the application is running (for examply by pushing a button, it is very important to add context.recreate() after you've changed the locale. Otherwise the current activity will not update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default language files from Android and set the language which should be used before calling setContentView().
Here's a short article about it: 
http://adrianvintu.com/blogengine/post/Force-Locale-on-Android.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**yes you fill your requirement using**

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
 Locale.setDefault(locale);
 Configuration config = new Configuration();
 config.locale = locale;
 context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

method and after that [follow this link for change app lang](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/multi-language-support-to-android-app)