# how to support localization in android library

Tags: android

I want to build an android library (jar file). The jar files needs to be localized. Like I have a class:

```
class MyMessageService
{
    //Needs to return different languages message according to locale
    String getMessage1(); 
}
```

I tried to package `res/values/string.xml` and `R.class` in the jar.

But in my main application which reference the jar, I call

```
 String s = this.getResources().getString(mylibrary.localize.R.string.hello);
```

I got "s" which is from my main project (resource id collides).

Is there any way to create an android library that support localization? I cannot let main application import my library's resource as my library is supposed to shipped alone.

Comment: have you read through this document? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://www.kobu.com/i18n/android/index-en.htm

Comment: Please note that I am working on library. Above two link are all about application, not library

Comment: My guess would be that you can do it only with an android library project, that you will depend on from your app project. If you include it only as a jar, it won't work, because the R file is generated when/before compiling and as your jar is already compiled, the strings ids won't be included. Just my 2c.

Comment: I think this is the answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/9852908/764275.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing lib a wrong way on Android..
I also faced problem like you to reuse UI component between different projects
Just give Android Library Project a try(lib.jar.path for package example), build the lib proj and now you get R class generated, reference the lib proj to your application proj(in project properties Android tab), and use lib.jar.path.R to find your string or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this can not be done in standart way with jar. But you can implement localization himself - current user locale can be retreived by Locale.getDefault(). After that you can build an switch and return corresponding to locale strings (it can be saved simply in code or in some external file).