# How to provide Arabic Language support in Android Application

Tags: android, localization, arabic

I have made an application in android but now I have to provide arabic language support. I have checked many of answers in stackoverflow but from any answer I didn't get correct answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852708/android-multi-language-support-without-localization
I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

To provide localization support for different languages, we need to add the language specific resources into separate folder. For eg:Inorder to provide layouts for Arabic language 
we need to create a separate folder under res folder i.e.,`res/layout-ar` like this.

In order to access the current language via code we can get the current language by calling

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

for more information look into following links:
for localization :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

for  RTL layout mirroring (Arabic like languages):http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Answer (score 0):

Also you may need to use 'onConfigChange' to your 'AndroidManifest' file with option 'locale'

Answer (score 0):

I am just a beginner but I have looked this question up and came up with this:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/android-string-localization#.VG5A_PmUeSp
 Eclipse provides string localization. However, when it translated the strings to Arabic, I had to double check the translation because Arabic has Feminism in Grammar and also some plural forms aren't that correct.

Answer (score 0):

- In AndroidManifest.xml:
  [SupportRtL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR5sY.png)
  this will enable alignments of images and text to right in Arabic and left in English
- Create two string resource layouts (one English, one Arabic)
  [string Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwyFp.png)
- Add the same string with the same name in the two layouts but change the value of the arabic string in the (ar\strings.xml)
- Same goes to each drawable item
  (Also for reference I'll add how you can create a resource that ar or RL)
  [creating arabic resourse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22MIN.png)
- Also either in the base activity to set the base local language 
          `app = (MyApplication)getApplicationContext();`
        `lang = Actions.setLocal(this);`using the function:
  [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhx8b.png)